# new pandas column based on multiplying two values in another pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a new column, with values based on multiplying a row of col_a by the new columns (col_b) previous value

desired output:

```
col_a.  col_b. 
1        na
2        2*1 (2)
3        3*2.(6)
4        4*6.(24)
5        5*24 (120)
```

I have tried using the following code and think I am close but could use some help

```
df['col_b'] = df['col_a'].apply(lambda x[n]: x[n] * x[n-1] for n in range(0, len(df)))
```

Edited as original problem changed. I have now attempted:

```
def func(df):
    for n in range(1, len(df)):
        df['col_b'] = df['col_a'][n]*df['col_b'][n-1]
        
    return df
```

But I am only getting NaNs

Comment: `df["col_a"]*(df["col_a"].shift())`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked however has made me understand I was asking the wrong question.

Comment: then try `df["col_a"].cumprod()`?